# How to reference the return value of a stored procedure called within a task in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a user defined stored procedure that returns a `VARIANT` type in snowflake. I would like to call this procedure from a task and log the return value into tables.

The task would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MY_TASK 
  SCHEDULE = '5 minute'
WHEN 
  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MY_STREAM') 
AS
CALL MY_PROCEDURE();

/* This procedure could return the following metrics that I need to log.
{
  timestamp: 1234567890,
  rows_affected: 1234,
  success: true
}
*/
```

Is this possible or do I need to include logging in the procedure?

Comment: Could you just modify your existing SP to write the output to a table instead of as an output?  Or create a stored procedure wrapper that does it for you?  A task can only execute a single SQL command, so you wouldn't be able to do it within the same task.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, I think I'll just have to add logging to the procedure itself. Thanks for looking into it @MikeWalton

Answer (score 0):

Any single SQL statement, or a call to a stored procedure, executed when the task runs.

You have to log it inside the stored procedure.

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#required-parameters